# Oracle connection from application throwing error but sqlplus is fine

Tags: oracle, oledb

I keep receiving this error:
Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.

as an exception when I'm running my application.

The application is targeted to 32bit machines and the computer is actually 64bit.

This was working fine yesterday and two months ago and now it isn't working it keeps throwing this error.

I have double checked my ORACLE_PATH and made sure that I have the oci.dll present as well as the ociw32.dll present and in fact they are in both Oracle11gcli/bin folder and the orcle11g/bin folder

I am able to connect using sqlplus and sqldeveloper.
When I log into sqlplus the says 64bit production but I doubt the 32/64 bit architecture is the problem since it was working for over 3 months just fine.

tnsnames and listener files all look okay aswell.

What am I missing?

Here is the exception:

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle Corporation and are part of the Oracle Version 7.3.3 or later client software installation.

Provider is unable to function until these components are installed.
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

Thanks

Comment: I have Oracle 11g installed

Comment: I am this is the exception error message if you look at the end it says "or later client installation"

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about Oracle Rdb, which is a database product Oracle acquired from Digital Equipment Corporation which runs on VAX/VMS systems? 7.3 is the most recent version of that product. It's completely different from the flagship Oracle product.

Comment: When you start Sqlplus and it says "64 bit" it means the connected database is 64 bit!

Comment: @WernfriedDomsheit I understand, but what I am saying is that it was working fine for 3 months so I doubt that is the issue the application I created is targeted for 32bit machine but it works fine on 64 bit machines just yesterday it stopped working.

Comment: I switched the application from "any cpu" to x86 in visual studio now I get this error:

System.InvalidOperationException: The 'MSDAORA' provider is not registered on the local machine.

Comment: What is the Connection String?

Comment: Please show your code. 'msdaora' does not exist for 64-bit, thus 'anyCPU' does not work on 64-bit Windows.